# Ordering two tables by one datetime with PHP, MYSQL (PDO)

Tags: mysql, sql

Here are some crazy issues I'm fighting with for a very long time now:
I have a two tables with identical structure, let's assume they are `dogs_table` and `cats_table`

```
dogs_table:
-id
-dog_posts
-dog_date

cats_table:
-id
-cat_posts
-cat_date
```

I would like to create a timeline from `dog_posts` and `cat_posts`, similar to this one:
[image]
`dog_posts` should go to the left side and `cat_posts` to the right but they must be joined as it's one table, ordered by datetime of each one. (Either way the timeline crushes). Until now I tried using `UNION`similar to this:

```
SELECT cat_posts as posts, cat_date as date, 'cats' as type from cats_table
UNION
SELECT dog_posts as posts, dog_date as date, 'dogs' as type from dogs_table
ORDER BY date desc
```

But this or similar `UNION` ways absolutely are not working to me, because the make both dogs and cats posts as one and I need to be able output a `row` either with dog_posts or cat_posts. So, I'm wondering if there is some better way than using `UNION` or maybe there is a way to achieve this result with `UNION` too, but I just don't know the right syntax. And I have no idea how to use `JOIN` too... So, any help will be highly appreciated, thanks a lot to everyone for attention.

Comment: I don't see how this query is not working. You have the `type` column which you can use to put the data either on the left or the right side of the timeline. And that should be done in PHP

Comment: But how can I use it? For example while($row = $stmt->fetch()){} outputs only cat_posts but I can' get other rows, Notice: Undefined index: is what I receive. How can I use type columns?

Comment: `if ($row['type']=='dogs') {/* display at left side */} else {/* display at right side */}` - Now it's just a HTML/CSS question.

Comment: Yes, thank you! It works, but still, I would like to have some other options and find a better solution. Maybe with the help of JOIN or else.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way of what I wrote in the comments is a **full outer join**.
Usually I don't use full outer joins, but when I do, I use the following method: Select all distinct values from the join columns of both tables (which are `dog_date` and `cat_date` in your case). Use it in a subquery and left join the two tables on that columns.

```sql
select dogs.dog_post, dates.date, cats.cat_post
from (
    select dog_date as date from dogs_table
    union 
    select cat_date as date from cats_table
) dates
left join dogs_table dogs on dogs.dog_date = dates.date
left join cats_table cats on cats.cat_date = dates.date
order by dates.date
```

However - I don't know what you are going to do, if multiple rows have the same date.

Comment: Is it possible to select few more rows from another table, called `users` for example? This table doesn't have `time` row, but I would wanna select id, username or else. What would the syntax be then?

Comment: It Doesn't look like it makes sence.

Comment: `$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id, username from users
UNION
SELECT cats_post, cat_date as date, 'cats' as type from c_positive
UNION
SELECT dogs_post, dog_date as date, 'dogs' as type from c_negative
ORDER BY date desc");` I tried to use this one, but got an error `Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1222 The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns`